# Update spark List control on dataProvider change

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am using spark List control which is bind to an instance of such class:

```
[Event(name="collectionChange", type="mx.events.CollectionEvent")]
public class HierarchicalCollectionListAdapter extends EventDispatcher implements IList
{
...
}
```

I want to make List fully re-draw each time when this collection send "reset" collectionChange event. Now to achieve this, each time after collection update I have to call this code:

```
var _itemRenderer:IFactory = _list.itemRenderer;
_list.itemRenderer = null;
_list.itemRenderer = _itemRenderer;
```

Is there any way to do it in more elegant way?

Comment: List should do this out of the box. Perhaps there's something wrong with your implementation of IList. Have you tracked whether the event is dispatched as expected?

Comment: @RIAstar yup, everything is Ok. I've put breakpoint in `ListBase.dataProvider_collectionChangeHandler` method and it hit when collection updated.

Comment: The problem is probably in your item renderers then.  If the list is firing collectionChange Events but your item renderers aren't updating, I would look at the way the bindings are set up in your value objects that you are using in the data and how you are binding to them in the renderer.  IE.. if you are just setting the properties in the renderer on set data() but do not have bindings set up, then if the data.imageURL (or whatever) property changes in the data provider, the renderer won't update.  Just a thought but I would look there.

Comment: @JasonReeves I'm not sure I understand what you just said.  Setting properties in set data() is an appropriate way to update a render without the use of binding. Use of Bindings in renderers causes all sorts of performance/memory issues. If the dataProvider has changed in such a way that the data changes; then set data should re-execute on the renderer; which should be able to update the display.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com ... interesting... I have always used bindings in my renderers and never saw problems with performance.  But, once you said this, I researched around and many people say be careful of it.  I wonder if I am just doing it cleanly?  Or if there are performance gains I am missing out on here.  :)  Gonna play and see.

Comment: @JasonReeves You could just be lucky. I have solved dozens of customer problems with the Flextras AutoComplete component by just teaching them to rewrite their itemRenderers.  In Mobile I'd say it is required not to use Binding in renders.

Comment: ok so i tried it without bindings... execution speed sped up... but updates didn't execute.  After noticing this, i looked in the adobe docs, and they use bindings as well.. including in their best practices optimization guide. so I'm confused as to why you say don't use them.  Without, sub properties don't trigger updates... with all works well.

Comment: @JasonReeves
>If the list is firing collectionChange Events but your item renderers aren't updating



My renderers are updating(I got `dataChange` event firing), but in some really strange way. For example: I got 3 elements in list, and after replacing 2nd element with other one in UI I can see strange things: 3d item, new item, again 3d item.

Comment: ok, then your problem sound like virtualization issues.  in your set data you should clear everything and always assume you have old data in there that needs to be removed.  Renderers are recycled so you gotta make sure you clear them out every time.   In my case in testing , I wasn't replacing items... just updating properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave my solution here in case if someone will have same problem.

Best thing that I could do - create extended list control, which will refresh itself each time on collection update. So, create new control, based on spark list and add this code there:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.IList;
        import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
        import mx.events.CollectionEventKind;

        /**
         * Subscribe to collection change event.
         */
        override public function set dataProvider(value:IList):void
        {
            if (dataProvider)
                dataProvider.removeEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE,
                    dataProvider_collectionChangeHandler);

            if (value)
                value.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, _collectionChangeHandler, false, 0, true);

            var _itemRenderer:IFactory = this.itemRenderer;
            this.itemRenderer = null;
            this.itemRenderer = _itemRenderer; 

            super.dataProvider = value;
        }

        /**
         * If collection has changed - redraw list by resetting itemRenderer.
         */
        private function _collectionChangeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            if (event is CollectionEvent)
            {
                var ce:CollectionEvent = CollectionEvent(event);

                // We don't need to refresh if any collection element will change.
                if(ce.kind != CollectionEventKind.UPDATE)
                {
                    var _itemRenderer:IFactory = this.itemRenderer;
                    this.itemRenderer = null;
                    this.itemRenderer = _itemRenderer;
                }
            }
        } 

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard for me to see whats going on here but it looks like your list `dataProvider` is not extending `ListCollectionView` so you can't use `refresh()`

However, you may be able to force a redraw using `invalidateDisplayList()`

I would try something like this:

```
_list.dataGroup.invalidateDisplayList();
```

Comment: My class `HierarchicalCollectionListAdapter` wrapping `HierarchicalCollectionView` class, which has `refresh()` and I can see, that event is fired on refreshing. `_list.dataGroup.invalidateDisplayList();` doesn't not help. Only resetting `itemRenderer` works.